# Email body is returned as encrypted text? How do I read the actual message?

Tags: python, gmail-api

As part of the payload returned for messages.get(), I get the following

```
  "parts": [
        {
            "body": {
                "data": "Q29udHJWxpZWYsIExvcmVtIElwc3VtIGlz......much longer",
```

How do read the actual message? Basically, how do I decrypt/decode this information so it's actual English text?

I'm using the Python libraries for the Gmail API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the data is base64 encoded so in python you would do something like that

```
import base64

string_enc = <some_base64_encoded_string>
string = base64.b64decode(string_enc)
```

Comment: Thank you, suggested an edit - namely to replace the  - and _ characters with + and /, respectively, for text/html mimeTypes.  For text/plain your code works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I think its base 64 *URL Encoded* which is different than Base 64 encoding.

Comment: This is correct. You want to use `base64.urlsafe_b64decode()` instead.